# How to draw a bitmap with per-pixel alpha onto a control's Canvas?

Tags: windows, delphi, user-interface, graphics, delphi-xe2

**Question**

What's the best way to draw a bitmap with a per-pixel alpha onto a control's Canvas?

My bitmap data is stored in a 2d array of 32-bit pixel values.

```
T32BitPixel = packed record
    Blue  : byte;
    Green : byte;
    Red   : byte;
    Alpha : byte;
end;
```

My control is a descendent of [TCustomTransparentControl](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Vcl.Controls.TCustomTransparentControl).

**Background**

For a GUI I'm building I need to draw semi-transparent controls over other controls and textured backgrounds. The control graphics are created using [AggPasMod](http://aggpasmod.sourceforge.net/) (a port of Anti-Grain Geometry).

TCustomTransparentControl.Canvas.Handle provides access to the [device context](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azz5wt61%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for drawing but I'm not sure how to blit the pixel data from there.

Comment: Are your pixels stored really that way or it's just a typo ? Usually the pixels of 32-bit bitmaps are stored as B,G,R,A not R,G,B,A.

Comment: Thanks TLama. Fixed that typo.

Comment: Re (Edit): First use something a bit more different, 220 is close to 255 for a visual test, use something like, f.i., 128. TLama's answer assumes that you've properly setup the alpha channel. You have not. After you setup pixel data, set `AlphaFormat` to `afPremultiplied` to let VCL properly calculate R,G,B from the alpha channel if you've got a recent Delphi version. If not, see `AC_SRC_ALPHA` in `BLENDFUNCTION`s documentation for how it is done.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz: Adding afPremultiplied doesn't seem to change anything. (I'm using Delphi XE2)

Comment: @Shannon - Read my comment again, set `afPremultiplied` **after** you've setup pixel data. Move the `Bitmap.AlphaFormat := afPreMultiplied;` line just before `BlendFunction.BlendOp :=..` line.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz: oops!! Sorry I missed an important detail. Setting 'afPremultiplied' indeed does the trick!! Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Shannon - You're welcome! Consider rolling back the question since the 'edit'ed part addresses a different issue than the originally asked question.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz: Good idea, I've removed the extra 'edited' section.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming, you have your pixel array composed like the image rows and pixels in them, I would do it this way. The `Canvas` parameter is a target canvas, the `X` and `Y` are coordinates, where the bitmap will be rendered in the target canvas and the `Pixels` is the pixel array:

```
type
  TPixel = packed record
    B: Byte;
    G: Byte;
    R: Byte;
    A: Byte;
  end;
  TPixelArray = array of array of TPixel;

procedure RenderBitmap(Canvas: TCanvas; X, Y: Integer; Pixels: TPixelArray);
var
  I: Integer;
  Size: Integer;
  Bitmap: TBitmap;
  BlendFunction: TBlendFunction;
begin
  Bitmap := TBitmap.Create;
  try
    Bitmap.PixelFormat := pf32bit;
    Bitmap.Width := Length(Pixels[0]);
    Bitmap.Height := Length(Pixels);
    Size := Bitmap.Width * SizeOf(TPixel);

    for I := 0 to Bitmap.Height - 1 do
      Move(Pixels[I][0], Bitmap.ScanLine[I]^, Size);

    BlendFunction.BlendOp := AC_SRC_OVER;
    BlendFunction.BlendFlags := 0;
    BlendFunction.SourceConstantAlpha := 255;
    BlendFunction.AlphaFormat := AC_SRC_ALPHA;
    AlphaBlend(Canvas.Handle, X, Y, Bitmap.Width, Bitmap.Height,
      Bitmap.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, Bitmap.Width, Bitmap.Height, BlendFunction);
  finally
    Bitmap.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks TLama. I'm not getting the results I expected with this code. (I'll add some details to my original question.)

Comment: Thanks for your help! Alpha blending is working as expected now. :)